# get user returns "AnonymousUser" on django

Tags: python, django

I followed this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms) creating a custom `User`.
in `views.py` I created a method preseting the user information by userid (i.e. /users/42) but the result is `AnonymousUser`. I should mention the db-record I'm trying to get is exist in my DB.

Here's my `models.py` file:

```
from django import forms
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, date_of_birth, password):
        """
        Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
        birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(email,
            password=password,
            date_of_birth=date_of_birth
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserProfileManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    #REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    # On Python 3: def __str__(self):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin


class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """A form for creating new users. Includes all the required
    fields, plus a repeated password."""
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('email', 'date_of_birth')

    def clean_password2(self):
        # Check that the two password entries match
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        # Save the provided password in hashed format
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Here's the the method to present the `User`:

```
def show_user(request, user_id):
    try:
        user = UserProfile.objects.get(id=user_id)
    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        return None
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'user': user,
    })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Comment: can you show us the where is the call of show_user() ? urls.py ? May be you regexp in urls.py does not give the expected ID ; may be you can print user_id in show_user then, to just check that.

Comment: what happens if you change the context variable name to, say, `myuser`. There's already a context variable named `user` injected by `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`.

Comment: @FoxMaSk I can print the user_id, so it passed correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth` injects a `user` variable into your context data, and variables injected by context processor can override those supplied into RequestContext.

> #### When context processors are applied
>
> When you use RequestContext, the variables you supply directly are
>   added first, followed any variables supplied by context processors.
>   This means that a context processor may overwrite a variable you’ve
>   supplied, so take care to avoid variable names which overlap with
>   those supplied by your context processors.
>
> Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/

Comment: I changed `user` to `userprofile` and now it works. thanks a lot!